# Retrieving items from ViewModel with a linq where clause that needs a JavaScript variable as a parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Index.cshtml razor view that lists NewsFeedPosts on it.
In the controller when in the Index() Action Method I am calling my repository initially getting all of the NewsFeedPosts along with their Comments like this:

```
var newsFeedPosts = _context.NewsFeedPosts
.Include(p => p.Comments)
.OrderBy(t => t.CreatedDate)
.ToList();
```

In the actual view I am doing something like this to only show the first 4:

```
<div id="comments">
     @foreach (var comment in post.Comments.Take(4))
     {
          ...
     }
</div>
```

Then I will have a link that says 'View additional comments', kind of like how StackOverflow does it.

**On Click of this link:**

I know I can get this does with an Ajax request calling an action Method called GetNewsFeedPostComments and simply loop through them and append to the #comments div.

However, since I am already retrieving all of the Comments on page load (as shown in the below code) is this really the best way to do this? I feel like there is a better way since I already have all Comments for each news feed post inside of my ViewModel already.

**Here is what my pages ViewModel looks like:**

```
public class NewsFeedPostIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<NewsFeedPostViewModel> NewsFeedPosts { get; set; }
}
```

and when the page initially loads here is how I am populating this ViewModel and sending it to the View:

```
// GET: NewsFeedPosts
public IActionResult Index()
{
    // Get a list of all NewsFeedPosts including comments
    var newsFeedPosts = _repository.GetAllNewsFeedPosts();

    var newsFeedPostViewModels = newsFeedPosts.Select(fp => new NewsFeedPostViewModel()
    {
        Id = fp.Id,
        Title = fp.Title,
        Content = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(fp.Content),
        Comments = fp.Comments
    }).ToList();

    NewsFeedPostIndexViewModel vm = new NewsFeedPostIndexViewModel()
    {
        NewsFeedPosts = newsFeedPostViewModels
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

So in this JavaScript function is there anyway to utilize what I already have bound in the ViewModel?

```
$(".lnkViewAdditionalComments").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var newsFeedPostId = $(this).attr('data-newsFeedPost-Id');

    // retrieve remaining comments by using skip(4) and loop through them
        var comments = @Html.Raw(Model.NewsFeedPostIndexViewModel.Where(f => f.Id = // need to pass JS string here: feedPostId)));
    // foreach $(#comments).append(".....");
});
```

Comment: Yes you can very well use the c# object data in javascript, but not the Javascript variable in c#

Comment: If you going to load them all, you may as well render them all (i.e. delete the `.Take(4)` but put them inside a (say) `<div class="comment">` and style all but the 1st 4 to be hidden. But unless there are only a handful of comments and you expect users to view them all on most occassions, you would be better to initially get only the first 4 in the controller and use ajax to get the rest

Comment: @StephenMuecke is right, it should be done that way. But if you for some reason want to get a solution for the method you are trying then I can help out. Let me know

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was actually thinking about that approach as such a simple way of doing it right on page load. Especially since the amount of comments won't get out of hand anyway. Thank you very much for reading this and giving me the best options.

Comment: @Reddy could you join a chat in here and talk through a couple of things with me? Just curious since it is my first time doing a 'View Additional Comments' kind of thing.

Comment: @BlakeRivell yes sure, how can I help you

Comment: @Reddy I am not sure if there is any other way to start a chat session besides having multiple comments in here.

Comment: lol, thats true. So basically My Idea was you can have a javascript object which hold the viewmodel data like a array of objects. and then when you want to take the additional coments you can just do a where search similar to what you are trying with little bit of extra code and extract only those comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104700/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-reddy).

Comment: @BlakeRivell, Its as simple as [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zm69k5s2/). Putting the model into a javascript object and then generating the html from it would be plain crazy :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke just curious to know. Rather than having our HTML built heavily its better to save the data into a variable and build HTML on demand right??

Comment: I don't see any point. That would mean you storing the data in memory, plus generating the html, and writing extra code to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use `grep` function in Js

```
@{ 
var GetAllComments = Model.FeedPosts.Select(x => x.Comments); 
} 

<script> 
var feedPostId = 1; 
var GetCommentJs =@(Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(GetAllComments))); 
var filterFata = $.grep(GetCommentJs, function (value, index) { 
return value.FeedPostId == feedPostId; 
}); 
</script>
```

> NOTE: you can use also  `slice` function to take limited number of
>   records after `grep`.

Comment: Is is fantastic now I don't have to make a separate call to my database, or have to render all of the additional comments in a hidden div on page load. Would I set the getAllComments variable on document ready or does it not matter?

Comment: Do it in document ready, but to get all comments only one time.

Comment: Hmm I don't have access to Json.Encode for some reason. Could this be because I am using ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC6?

Comment: I am trying to get all of the comments from all of the newsfeedposts is this not going to be possible? Can I only get the entire VM? var allComments = @Html.Raw(Model.NewsFeedPosts.Select(fp => fp.Comments)); isn't working. It is kind of weird because I am attempting to select list of lists from a complex type

Comment: Forget about what I just said, I was thinking of getting a list of all of the Comments somehow, but instead you were just having me pull the actual NewsFeedPost where Id matches the JavaScript Id. So I am attempting it exactly how you showed me but getting the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal

Comment: ok, Then first Get Only Comment in your C# code block then put those list of comments in Js . @{}

Comment: Hmm I wonder if I can use JSON.parse() around the entire thing because I keep getting an Unterminated template literal error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104704/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-blake-rivell).